# Уязвимость PHP-кода (eval inj)

Tags: безопасность, php

Всем здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём уязвимость php кода, представленного ниже.
Насколько я понял, злоумышленник может получать значения всех переменных в коде (в том числе и глобальных). Есть ли в этом коде возможность исполнения произвольного кода?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

**SOURCE:**

```
<?
$user_input = str_replace(array("\\","'", '"'), "", $_GET["user_input"]);

eval("echo(\"$user_input\");");

?>
```

**UPDATE:**
Добрые люди подсказали пример обхода кавычек.
например передать в качестве templateTitle  {${phpinfo()}} ну и прочие вкусные интересные функции.
Не совсем понимаю почему фигурные скобки помогают обойти фильтрацию. Видимо надо манцы по пхп пойти читать.

Comment: ну да, если написать в гет что-то типа такого

    print_r($_SESSION)

Comment: вообще не понимаю сути вопроса, просто смиритесь с тем, что любого рода `eval` от лукавого ( JSON не в счет :) ) и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если как-то обойти замену двойной кавычки и обратного слэша, то можно выполнить любой код, передав его в переменную `templateTitle`. Пока не придумал, как передать `\"` так, чтобы пройти замену их на пустую строку.

Без замены, было бы примерно так:

```
http://site.ru/source.php?templateTitle=\");var_dump($GLOBALS);echo(\"Ok
```

Comment: ну да. я вот тоже пару часов на раздумья и гугл потратил чтобы придумать как фильтр обойти и кавычку внедрить, но ничего не придумал к сожалению

Comment: Может, вставить в запрос ещё одну переменную, а в ней замена уже не производится:

    source.php?templateTitle=$_GET[test]&test=";